# Using split in python on excel to get two parameter

Tags: python, excel, string, plot

I'm getting really confused with all the information on here using 'split' in python. Basically I want to write a code which opens a spreadsheet (with two columns in it) and the function I write will use the first column as x's and the second column as y's and then it will plot it in the x-y plane.

I thought I would use line.splitlines to cut each line in excel into (x,y) but I keep getting

```
'ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack'
```

- I don't know what this means?

Below is what I've written so far,  (xdir is an initial condition for a different part of my question):

```
def plotMo(filename, xdir):
    infile = open(filename)
    data = []
    for line in infile:
        x,y = line.splitlines()
        x = float(x)
        y = float(y)
        data.append([x,y])
    infile.close()
    return data 
plt.plot(x,y)
```

For example with

```
0       0.049976
0.01    0.049902
0.02    0.04978
0.03    0.049609
0.04    0.04939
0.05    0.049123
0.06    0.048807
```

I would want to the first point in my plane to be (0, 0.049976) and the second plot to be (0.01, 0.049902).

Answer (score 1):

`x,y = line.splitlines()` tries to split the current line into several lines.

Since `splitlines` returns only 1 element, there's an error because python cannot find a value to assign to `y`.

What you want is `x,y = line.split()` which will split the line according to 1 or more spaces (like `awk` would do) if no parameter is specified.

However it depends of the format: if there are blank lines you'll get the "unpack" problem at some point, so to be safe and skip malformed lines, write:

```
items = line.split()
if len(items)==2: x,y = items
```

To sum it up, a more pythonic, shorter & safer way of writing your routine would be:

```
def plotMo(filename):
    with open(filename) as infile:
        data = []
        for line in infile:
            items = line.split()
            if len(items)==2:
                data.append([float(e) for e in items])
    return data
```

(maybe it could be condensed more, but that's good for starters)

Comment: I originally used `x,y = line.split()` but it gives the same error.

Comment: see my edit. If your file contains a blank line (ex: in the end, it's very common) you have to filter it out, like I just did.

Comment: Also now with your more pythonic way it says `ValueError: could not convert string to float` - is this a related problem or a different problem

Comment: I just deleted my pythonic way. I think you didn't post a representative example of your input file...